# View is invisible

Tags: android, android-view

When playing the video full screen, other views disappear in the layout，but `getVisibility()` returned to `VISIBLE` and `isShown()` returned to `true`.
Who met the same problem, or have a good solution, please tell me, thank you.

It's activity_player.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/player"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

<!--Used to play the video-->
<com.mediaplay.MySurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--Used to play the marquee-->
<com.mediaplay.AutoScrollTextView
    android:id="@+id/marqueeView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

It's code(The code is too much, I can only capture important part ):

```
// play video
public void start() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null && mIsPrepared) {
        LOG("MediaPlayer start");
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

// play marquee, it extends TextView
private void initTextView() {

    if (marquee == null) return;

    marquee.requestFocus();
    marquee.setSelected(true);
    marquee.bringToFront();
    marquee.startScroll();
 }

public void startScroll() {
    isStarting = true;
    invalidate();
}
```

1. I try to use FrameLayout instead, it doesn't work
2. Here are some strange things, when the show toast or pop-up dialog，marqueeview can show,but once they disappear，marqueeview will disappear.
3. One thing is for sure,don't call mediaplayer.start(),marqueeview can show,but once called, it will disappear.
4. Android4.2.2 no probleams, android4.4.4 will have probleams

Comment: Some code would be nicer to see, you know... :/

Comment: @Victor : Please post some code & (thumbs up) if you are using FrameLayout then your View could have gone in the Background so try, YOUR_VIEW.bringToFront();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they don't disappear but the video is simply over the other views? You can use a relative layout to make sure the views are over the video.

Code would be nice though.

Comment: I have used a relative layout, and I found some strange things , when display a toast or pop up a dialog, the view can display, and I have called bringToFront(),it doesn't work